# Is worrying about too many CNAMEs a micro optimization?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

We have a whitelabel platform and I'm thinking about making one of my 'lower' domain names an A record instead of a CNAME, because I'm worried about too many cname redirects.

The whole stack would be around 4/5 cname records.

Is this a micro optimization or does it need to be thought through?

Comment: You shouldn't have a 'stack' of cnames. Its fine having a tree of many cnames pointing to the same A record but not a chain of cnames.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing as too many CNAME redirects, so reducing the number that lead to your final record is not just a micro optimization.

Unbound hardcodes a limit to prevent CNAME loops ([header](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/blob/46939294710d24a37f9f838141f26e6b063b01f3/iterator/iterator.h#L63), [source](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/blob/46939294710d24a37f9f838141f26e6b063b01f3/iterator/iterator.c#L1238)). Having to resolve too many CNAMES can results in SERVFAIL even when there is no loop.

Answer (score 1):

It may cause a very brief extra delay the first time a particular user accesses (that is, looks up) your service. Exactly how long depends on too many factors to say for sure, but it should not be noticeable (particularly not if all `CNAME`s are in domains hosted at the same servers).

If you want an example of someone big doing this sort of thing, have a look at `www.microsoft.com`, which chains three `CNAME`s.